# stl containers as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, stl

i am trying to write a selection sort template function for stl containers
(only for vectors , lists) this is my code

```
 template<typename T, template <T, typename =std::allocator<T>> class TContainer>


  void selection_sort(TContainer &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T,T)){
     int lowest_index;

      for(int i=0;i<length;i++){
         lowest_index=i;
         for(int j=i+1;j<length;j++){
            if(comparisonFcn(vla[j],vla[lowest_index])){
                lowest_index=j;
           }
         }
        std::swap(vla[i],vla[lowest_index]);
        std::cout<<i <<" "<<vla[i]<<std::endl;
}
 }


 //ascending function
 template <typename T>
bool ascending(T x,T y){
 return x<y;
 }
//descending function
template <typename T>
bool descending(T x,T y){
return x>y;
}

int main()
{

std::vector<int>vec={1,2,3,4};
selection_sort(vec,4,descending);
return 0;
  }
```

i have got the following errors:

```
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:32: error: variable or field ‘selection_sort’ declared void
  void selection_sort(TContainer const &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T, T)){

 /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:43: error: expected primary-expression before ‘int’
  void selection_sort(TContainer const &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T, T)){
                                       ^
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:62: error: ‘comparisonFcn’ was not declared in this scope
    void selection_sort(TContainer const &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T, T)){
                                                          ^
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:78: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
   void selection_sort(TContainer const &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T, T)){
                                                                          ^
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:81: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
   void selection_sort(TContainer const &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T, T)){

  ^
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:23:81: error: expression cannot be used as a function
 /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
  /home/ubuntu/workspace/hello-cpp-world.cc:54:37: error: ‘selection_sort’ was not declared in this scope
```

is it possible to template these type of functions for stl containers as parameters.could anyone tell me how to write the correct format for templating in these situations?

Answer (score 3):

You should change your declaration of `selection_sort` into

```
template<typename T, template <typename U, typename =std::allocator<U>> class TContainer>
void selection_sort(TContainer<T> &vla,int length, bool (*comparisonFcn)(T,T)){
    // as before
}
```

The `TContainer` is a template-template parameter, for which the parameters also need to be prefixed with either `typename` or `class`. Here's the [**fully working example**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/cmPApw1orJDCkY5C) of your code.

Note: it is recommended that you give `selection_sort` the same signature as `std::sort`, i.e. using iterators and a general function object as parameters, e.g. [**something like**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24650626/819272)

```
template<class FwdIt, class Compare = std::less<>>
void selection_sort(FwdIt first, FwdIt last, Compare cmp = Compare{})
```